# Is it safe to use java.awt.Robot inside JavaFX stage?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have the following code inside a stage `init()` method, to press "SPACE" when the window opens:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    try {
        java.awt.Robot r = new java.awt.Robot();
        r.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        r.keyRelease(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

But as Robot belongs to java.awt package, and knowing that JavaFX runs in a different thread than Swing/awt, i don't know if this is safe or not.
All i know is that it does what i want, but will it work always? Should i replace this code for something else?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, i've used it in a normal Thread (not using Platform.runLater()) and it worked fine even with UI Events like this:

```
static Robot robot=null;

private void initialize(){
        Thread hilo=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    robot=new Robot();
                    robot.waitForIdle();
                } catch (AWTException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }});

        hilo.start();
}
```

and then the event method

```
public static void handleMultiSelectIn(){
        try{
            if(togleMulti.isSelected())
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            System.out.println("In:"+togleMulti.isSelected());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX 8 introduced a `SwingNode` class that provides reverse integration and enables to embed Swing components in JavaFX applications.
`java.awt.Robot` is not directly related to Swing, but can definitely affect swing components.

**SwingNode Class**
To specify the content of the SwingNode object, call the setContent method, which accepts an instance of the javax.swing.JComponent class.
You can call the setContent method on either the JavaFX application thread or event dispatch thread (EDT).
However, **to access** the Swing content, ensure that your code runs on EDT, because the standard Swing threading restrictions apply.

You can check the official JavaFX docs over at:
[Embedding Swing Content in JavaFX Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/embed-swing.htm)